# Python ExchangeLib is not working due to the backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo error

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

I'm trying to send an email to outlook using ExchangeLib. However, it got failed with the below error.

```
 File "DeliverEmailResult.py", line 31, in __init__
    credentials=Credentials(self._from_user, self._password),
  File "C:\Users\..\Email Delivery\emailenv\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.default_timezone = default_timezone or EWSTimeZone.localzone()
  File "C:\Users\..Email Delivery\emailenv\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\ewsdatetime.py", line 264, in localzone
    return cls.from_pytz(tz)
  File "C:\Users\..Email Delivery\emailenv\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\ewsdatetime.py", line 244, in from_pytz
    self_cls.ms_id = cls.PYTZ_TO_MS_MAP[tz.zone][0]
AttributeError: 'backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo' object has no attribute 'zone'
```

I tried to solve this but couldn't get the right answer for this. Kindly help someone to identify the exact issue. Kindly inform in case any other alternatives are available or not for this solution. All suggestions are welcomed
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in exchangelib 3.3. You need to upgrade your version of exchangelib.